# Error While commiting to Github

Tags: github, github-pages, github-for-windows

remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/vivekghanchi/portfolio.git/' not found

Comment: Are you sure that repository exists?

Comment: even in the browser it is not available

Comment: the repository is deleted but I was committing to a new repository after than also  it is showing this

Comment: What `git` command are you executing? your title says `commiting to GitHub`, but you don't commit to GitHub, you commit locally and push to GitHub.

Comment: Yeah,I have pushed it to the GitHub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first to create your repository in GitHub (it's done directly in your Web browser). Then you can do a `git push` to upload your local commits to the new repository.

Also, after creating your GitHub repository, make sure the url you are pushing to matches that of GitHub, I notice an extra `/` at the end of your url, which should not be there.

To see the url you are pushing to, issue:

```
git remote -v
```

Answer (score 2):

> the repository is deleted but I was committing to a new repository after than also it is showing this

Committing is a local operation.

Make sure your remote url matches the one of your new repo.
Update it with:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/repo
git remote set-url https://github.com/vivekghanchi/aNewRepo
```

Then try to push again:

```
git push
```

Pushing is not "committing to GitHub", but rather "publishing your local commits to your upstream GitHub repository".

Answer (score 0):

You need first to create your repository in GitHub (it's done directly in your Web browser). Then you can do a git push to upload your local commits to the new repository.

Committing is a local operation.

or your can add already existing repo

```
git remote add origin remote repository URL
```